# Parse specific JSON with perl

Tags: perl

I have this:

```
{"First":"ID", "Second":"{\"@cond\": [true, false]}"}
```

I have written a code:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature 'say';
use JSON;
use utf8;

my $data = do { local $/; <DATA> };
my $d = decode_json($data);

$d->{Second} = decode_json( $d->{Second} );
say extractt($d);

sub extractt{
    my $inf = $d->{Second}{cond}[0]
    return $inf
}
__DATA__
{"First":"ID", "Second":"{\"@cond\": [true, false]}"}
```

My desired output is 'true, false' as a string.

However, i get nothing. What im doing wrong? How to fix it?

Comment: That isn't JSON. https://jsonlint.com/ will highlight the errors.

Comment: Well, after the edit, the problem is that you are using `decode_json` on something that isn't JSON. It doesn't look like any common data format that I know do your options are (a) write a custom parser or (b) complain to whomever gave you the data until they give it to you in JSON or another standard format.

Comment: What is `$m`? Where does that variable suddenly appear from?

Comment: @DaveCross i edited). It was $d

Comment: Please at least check that your code compiles before sharing it with us. You have a missing semicolon and you're using `DATA` where I'm pretty sure you mean `__DATA__`. Why make it so hard for us to help you?

Comment: @DaveCross right, sorry

Comment: It still doesn't compile. What is `rec2`? What is `msg`? You're still missing a semicolon (at the end of the first line in `extractt()`).

Answer (score 2):

Used the script to generated the needed JSON for testing see the commented code.

Remember that perl does not use the words `true` and `false` as boolean indicators.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature 'say';
use JSON;
use utf8;

# Used to generate the JSON data expected by the program
#my $data = {
#   First => 'ID',
#   Second => encode_json ({ cond => ['true', 'false'] })
#};
#
#say encode_json ($data);

# The original code with the JSON data updated

my $data = do { local $/; <DATA> };
my $d = decode_json($data);

$d->{Second} = from_json( $d->{Second} );
say 'rec1 '.extractt ($d, 0);
say 'rec2 '.extractt ($d, 1);

sub extractt{
    my $data = shift;
    my $index = shift;
    my $inf = $data->{Second}{cond}[$index];
    return $inf;
}
__DATA__
{"First":"ID","Second":"{\"cond\":[\"true\",\"false\"]}"}
```

If the JSON data need to be boolean true and false

```
{"First":"ID","Second":"{\"cond\":[true,false]}"}
```

the extractt method will see the values in perl as 1 and 0 so a small change will be needed to get the words returned:

```
my $inf = ($data->{Second}{cond}[$index])? 'true' : 'false';
```

Comment: `decode_json` expects JSON encoded using UTF-8, while `from_json` expects decoded text (a string of Unicode Code Points). `from_json` is used for the inner JSON because the `decode_json` returned decoded text.